# Qt + search engine API

Tags: qt, http-post, google-search

I need google (or other engine) search in my *desktop* program.
Could you please give me an example how to send a POST request to API and get the answer.
I use Qt and C++.

For example this code doesn't work (it's about yandex API):

```
QString* query = new QString("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>"
                             "<request><query>" + ui->search_le->text().toUtf8() +
                             "</query><groupings><groupby attr=""d"""
                             "mode=""deep""groups-on-page=""10""docs-in-group=""1"" />"
                             "</groupings></request>");

QUrl apiurl = QUrl("http://xmlsearch.yandex.ru/xmlsearch?user=*******&"
                   "key=03.*******:**************f01e29f007af7994e951");

manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
request = new QNetworkRequest(apiurl);
reply = manager->post(*request, query->toUtf8());

QString answer = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll());
```

And I really don't know how to find the problem.

Thanks all who will be able to help me.

Comment: Your XML breaks if the search string contains XML markup (<, >, etc.). Better use QXmlStreamWriter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Read about Signals and slots in Qt. http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/signalsandslots.html

You have to connect QNetworkAccessManager's `finished()` signal to your own slot and then call reply->readAll();

Do this before you call the post method.

```
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
     this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

Then implement the `replyFinished` method in your class.

```
MyClass::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
 QString answer = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll());     
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have the answer as well as mistakes =) But now I know where is the problem. It's strange why the program didn't work without catching the finished() signal.